# how to use weinre with browsersync

Tags: windows, ipad, browser-sync, weinre

Windows 10,
iPad

I'm running browsersync and trying to debug an iPad with this command:

`browser-sync start --proxy "www.mysite.com" --host my-ip-address --files /my-directory`

On the iPad I'm accessing the "External Url" listed in the command window. On my desktop machine I can access the browsersync UI and enable things like "CSS Outlining" and the outlines show on the iPad but I'm trying to figure out how to get console errors from the iPad visible on my machine in weinre.

The odd thing is I can type `alert('hi');` into the weinre console on my desktop and it will show the alret on the ipad, but none of the console errors from the ipad are showing on the weinre console.

Any suggestions? Is there something better than weinre for debugging an iPad on a Windows machine?

Thanks.